# QStringList.size returning two values

Tags: c++, qt, variables, size

In this section of my code I want to return the size of my QStringList

```
QStringList Attribute;
int tableSize = 0;


    QString string= reply->readAll();
    QRegExp expretion("[{}]");

    Attribute = string.split(expretion);
    tableSize = Attribute.size();
    qDebug()<<tableSize;
```

`qDebug()<<tableSize;` This is returning to me two values (1 and 7)

Value of **string**

```
[
  {
    "idInstallation": 10,
    "tstId": 1,
    "knockPerTest": 10,
    "description": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "state": "1",
    "dateCreation": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStart": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "datePause": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStop": "2019-07-09T12:46:00"
  },
  {
    "idInstallation": 10,
    "tstId": 2,
    "knockPerTest": 20,
    "description": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    "state": "1",
    "dateCreation": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStart": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "datePause": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStop": "2019-07-09T12:46:00"
  },
  {
    "idInstallation": 10,
    "tstId": 3,
    "knockPerTest": 30,
    "description": "ccccccccccccccccccccc",
    "state": "1",
    "dateCreation": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStart": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "datePause": "2019-07-09T12:46:00",
    "dateStop": "2019-07-09T12:46:00"
  }
]
```

My goal using **split** is to separate the jason records I'm getting.
for example

```
Attribute = json.split(expretion);
```

I can't find the error

When I print to the console, it returns me the following values:

[image: output]

Comment: Please show us the exact text that is printed, the question right now is not clear enough.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza 
I edited the question and put an image of the output of my code, I hope you can better understand my doubt.

thank you

Comment: There's not enough information, the image doesn't help either. Please provide more code otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza sorry for the lack of information
I added more information on the question

Comment: The code is fine, the current example prints only one time, you're probably just calling it multiple times somehow.

Comment: I tested with the following string and i get output of the size is 5. Could you please show the output of qDebug() << Attribute?

     QString string= "[ { aaa } { bbb } ]";